# Can't find the json file that I created

Tags: swift, swiftui

I used this code for encoding some data into a json file, but I can't really find the location of the file.

```swift
func save () {
    let users: [UserCredentials] = []
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    
    do {
        let data = try encoder.encode(users)
        let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("users.json")
        try data.write(to: url)
    } catch {
        print("Error encoding JSON: \(error)")
    }
}
```

I didn't find anything in the Document directory. Then I found out that I have to go to my Bundle ID that's located in library/application support, but I didn't find mine there.
Any idea where that json file is hiding?

Comment: are you running it in ios?

Comment: no, I am running it in simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Insert the line `print(url.path)` after the `let url...` line.
2. Run the code.
3. Copy (⌘C) the printed path in the console.
4. Switch to Finder, press ⇧⌘G, then ⌘V and return.